# Saving charts with dynamic view

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

In my WinForms application, I have to display line graphs.

One feature which I need to implement in my application is saving the chart to a file. Once the chart is saved and the application is closed, the saved chart can be opened and the user can zoom-in/zoom-out the chart for analysis.

Most charting tools enable user to save the chart to an image file like .png/.jpg etc., which are static.

I want to achieve something like [Matlab's FIG file](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html). Are there controls which already do this? Or if I have to implement it myself, what is the best approach?

Comment: You may want to look into the [save formats wmf etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartimageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Also into [chart serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456693%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: My answer was wrong/incomplete; rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Save as `Jpg` or `Png` in a size **large enough to zoom** in. To do so you would **enlarge** the chart before saving and then **shrink** it again.
- Save in one of the `emf` formats. This saves a vector format, so zooming in works very well, even at large zoom factors. ((erroneous rant omitted))
- Save to `XML`. This means **serializing**, either using the standard options or by marking certain properties as serializable or non-serializable. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456693%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info! This code is straight from the link:

  ```
  string yourChartDataFile = "d:\\SavedChartData.xml";

  private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      chart1.Serializer.Save(yourChartDataFile);
  }

  private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      chart1.Serializer.Load(yourChartDataFile);
  }
  ```

To display the resulting file you need another `chart` control, obviously.

I found the two-liner above to work pretty well without adding frills, but you may need or want to save things like current zoom state or annotation states; I'm not sure just what does get serialized out of the box and what does not..

**Update** Actually you can view and work with `emf` by loading them into a [`Metafile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile(v=vs.110).aspx), which can be loaded into a `PictureBox` or drawn in a suitable size with `Graphics.DrawImage`..

Comment: Nice answer..I'll try ASAP and mark as answer. Thanks a lot..:)