# How to resize chart more than screen resolution?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a C# 4.7 WinForms application with line chart. I want to save chart image with very large resolution e.g 10000x2000. Here is what I have archived:

```
Form1.Width = 3860; //my screen width resolution - maximum allowed
Form1.Height = 1080; //my screen height resolution - maximum allowed
chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
chart1.SaveImage(saveFile.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

That code saves jpeg image with 3860x1080 resolution and i can zoom in points I need. But it is not enough and I want to enlarge my form **or chart** to 
 get an image like 10000x2000, VS says it cannot be larger than my screen.
I have a lot of data on this chart, so bigger form provides me with more data on a chart. Picture is required for other people to see the maximum info.

How can I do it?

Comment: VS is right; you can't make a form larger than your screen. That is because the user needs to see your form to get access to things like the close box, toolbar, edges, and so on, so a form larger than the screen wouldn't be usable. If you [explained why you think you need this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) we may be able to help.

Comment: This is not user app, for personal use only. I need a very large picture of my graph with maximum info like points etc

Comment: Screen is not enough for me anyway. I need to send this graph to analitics departmet so they could see maximum info on it. So I need a very large picture of a graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple.

All you need to do is create the `Chart` in code without displaying it on screen.

Now you can size it as needed..:

```
Chart bigChart = new Chart();
bigChart.ChartAreas.Add("ca");
Series s1 = bigChart.Series.Add("s1");
s1.BorderWidth = 5;
s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

// testdata 

Random rnd = new Random(8);
for (int i = 0; i < 111; i++)
{
    s1.Points.AddXY(rnd.Next(123) + i, rnd.Next(12 * i)) ;
}

bigChart.Size = new Size(10000, 8000);

bigChart.SaveImage(filename, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

A few notes:

- You may want to add a `Legend` as well, as the dynamically created `Chart` has none of the default elements..
- If you want to you can use a chart you have, serialize its content to a file (or stream) and then **load** (deserialize) it into the big chart..
- The automatic smartness of MSChart tends to hit some limit when the sizes grow a lot; so brace yourself for tweaking some settings for line width, Fonts etc..
- You also may want to load the saved image and set the **dpi** to a bigger values than the default, which is the screen resolution..
- Final remark: Sometimes it is better to save the chart as a **vector** format; these are also provided in the SaveImage method.

**Update:** Maybe you want to combine vector and pixel formats as in Jimi's last comments.

You may want to study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002647/saving-charts-with-dynamic-view/32013687?r=SearchResults&s=1|25.1987#32013687) post which discusses a few general options.

Comment: I was about to say what you added in the edit: `ChartImageFormat.Emf` saves a readable (AI, CorelDraw etc.) vector version of the chart. It can then be printed at any resolution or size.

Comment: Many thanks, TaW, I've just deleted chart1 from form controls and resized it - that worked and saved legend. I want to increase dpi, how can i do this, there's no property dpi?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to load the image after saving and then use bitmap.SetResolution() and save again. If you use png, as you should (!) quality will not suffer.

Comment: @ Elperro  Try something like: `chart1.SaveImage(@"X:\chart1.emf", ChartImageFormat.Emf); using (var bmp = new Bitmap(10000, 2000)) using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) { g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(@"X:\chart1.emf", true), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size)); bmp.Save(@"X:\chart1.png", ImageFormat.Png); }`

Comment: @Elperro You can specify the DPI resolution with `bmp.SetResolution(300f, 300f);` (300 dpi) if you need to.